# Allow a Python typer option to appear anywhere on the command line

Tags: python, typer

Consider the following typer-based Python program:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python
import typer
app = typer.Typer()
from typing_extensions import Annotated

VERBOSE = False

books_app = typer.Typer()
app.add_typer(books_app, name="books")

authors_app = typer.Typer()
app.add_typer(authors_app, name="authors")
### 
@books_app.command("list")
def books_list() -> str:
    if (VERBOSE):
        print("entering 'books_list'")

@books_app.command("delete")
def books_delete(
    book_name: Annotated[str, typer.Argument(help="name of book to delete")],
) -> str:
    if (VERBOSE):
        print("entering 'books_delete'")                                                                                                 
###
@app.callback(no_args_is_help=True, invoke_without_command=True)
def main(ctx: typer.Context,
        verbose: Annotated[bool, typer.Option("--verbose", "-v", help="runs in verbose mode")] = False
) -> None:
    global VERBOSE
    if (verbose):
        VERBOSE = True

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app()
```

I would like to be able to put the "global" option `--verbose` anywhere on the command line. That is, I want each of the following to work the same way:

```
$ ./myapp --verbose books list
$ ./myapp books --verbose list
$ ./myapp books list --verbose
```

As the above program is written only the first of the above three invocations works.

One way to accomplish this would be to add the `--verbose` option to each command/subcommand function definitions. However, that seems inefficient, especially if I have many command and subcommands.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Note that POSIX-standard command-line option parsing conventions only allow options to come before positional arguments -- `typer` is thus more conformant than other, more GNU-influenced libraries by doing this. There are good reasons for the convention -- without it using an end-of-options sigil is more frequently required for disambiguation -- so I'd urge you to reconsider the requirement and hew closer to the older standard. (See https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html#tag_12_02, guideline 9)

Comment: (to be a little more concrete re: "end-of-options sigil" -- compare `ls -- "$file"` and `ls "$file"` when you're trying to list a file whose name starts with a dash; that `--` sigil is necessary in any event when there are no preceding positional arguments before an argument that may or may not start with a dash, but in a tool that follows standardized convention it's not needed after _any_ positional argument).